# jQuery select both first and last row of a table in single selective statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, pagination

I was trying to implement table pagination using [this](http://neoalchemy.org/tablePagination.html) plugin. The reason I selected this is because it has an option to ignore rows.

```
 var options = {
     currPage: 2,
     ignoreRows: $('tbody tr:last', $('#menuTable2')),
     optionsForRows: [2, 3, 5],
     rowsPerPage: 5,
     firstArrow: (new Image()).src = "./images/firstBlue.gif",
     prevArrow: (new Image()).src = "./images/prevBlue.gif",
     lastArrow: (new Image()).src = "./images/lastBlue.gif",
     nextArrow: (new Image()).src = "./images/nextBlue.gif",
     topNav: true
 }
 $('#menuTable2').tablePagination(options);
```

Passing rows as

```
ignoreRows: $('tbody tr:last', $('#menuTable2'))
```

we can ignore them. I want to **ignore both first and last row**.

How to select both of them and pass as a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
ignoreRows: $('tbody tr:last, tbody tr:first', $('#menuTable2')),
```

which should be same as

```
ignoreRows: $('#menuTable2 tbody').find('tr:first, tr:last'),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ignoreRows =     $('#menuTable2 tbody').find('tr:first, tr:last');
```